# Safe UI cannot show transaction history for a local setup

Tags: gnosis-safe, gnosis, safe-core

Appreciate the hard work of team! I am following the doc to setup everything locally and on aws, seems every thing works fine including safe wallet creation, transaction submission and signing, but the only part that doesn’t seems to normal is transaction history (see the image below), i have been checking the source code and config for some time, but if anyone can help on this would be very appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this question relates to Safe{Wallet}, not Safe{Core}. Feel free to reach out to https://help.safe.global for topics related to our UI!

Hope it helps,
Louis